# Question on Wave functions and State vector in our hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics

So I am reading through Griffiths and I am a little stuck. He says the state of a quantum system can be represented by some state $\left|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>\in \mathcal{H}$. However we can express this state in any number of basis. All of this makes sense. Where he loses me though is he then goes on to say that our wave function $\Psi(x,t)$ is actually the coefficient of the expansion of $\left|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>$ in the basis of position eigenfunctions.

Namely: $$\Psi(x,t)=\left<x|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>$$

Hasn't $\Psi(x,t)$ been an element of our Hilbert Space $L^2[a,b]$ this whole time? so why is our wave function now a scalar instead of a vector (element of $\mathcal{H}$)?

Comment: A function is an infinite dimensional vector.

Comment: But the inner product of two vectors i.e. $\left<x|\mathscr{s}(t)\right> \in \mathbb{C}$ so by the definition that Griffiths gives wouldnt $\Psi(x,t)$ be a scalar?

Comment: The _function_ $\Psi$ _evaluated at the point_ $x$ is a complex number, but this is the same thing as saying "the $z$-component of a position vector is a real number". Since the $|x\rangle$ vectors are the basis vectors of the Hilbert space, what you are doing in that inner product is simply selecting a particular component of a vector. The function _itself_ (i.e. the collection of all of its "components") is still a vector.

Comment: This won't answer your question, but said in another way: consider $u,v \in \mathbb{R}$. $2+3 = 5$ but if I write $u + v$ then I have an expression, whose evaluate depends on what $u$ and $v$ are. Therefore, let me define a function $f: (u,v) \mapsto (u+v)$ with $f(u,v) := u + v$. Likewise, me naively looking at your first equation from a math perspective, we have the same thing. $\left<1 \text{meter}|s(2 \text{seconds})\right> \in \mathbb{C}$. And now here's where I'm going to guess what is happening because I don't know the physics. $x$ means something and $t$ means something, but both

Comment: are variables so we define a function $\Psi : (x,t) \mapsto \left<x|s(t)\right>$ or $\Psi(x,t) := \left < x|s(t)\right >$. I remember reading this textbook before. I'm pretty sure the symbol $\Psi$ is being overloaded [often done in physics. Overloading is like $x = x(t)$ where $x$ is meant to stand for the name of a function (defined somewhere else on your sheet of paper) and also a variable $x$. It's better to write something like $y = f(x)$ where $f$ is a function (defined somewhere) and $y = f(x)$ is an equation satisfied by some $(x,y)$ pair] Because Griffiths recognized this, he

Comment: suddenly switches to this $s$ notation for the state. But something is still confusing me. It's not all fitting together, his chapter 3, with language he used in previous chapters (as well as other sources writing things like, instead of the equation you have with $s$ and $\Psi$, they have both as $\Psi$ or both as $\psi$). I need to more careful read his book maybe

Comment: @DWade64 if you look at the answer below you can see me work through what it means. Basically $\Psi(x,t)$ is just the coefficient of the component of $\left|\Psi(x,t)\right>$ in some basis $\left|x\right>$  so to be clear: $$\left|\Psi(x,t)\right>=\sum_{i \in I} \left|x_i\right>\left<x_i|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>$$ where $I$ is some indexing set.

Comment: Wouldn't that be overloading as well? It's like saying $\vec{r} = \vec{r}\hat{x} + \vec{r}\hat{y}$, or something like that? I'm getting confused on the differences between $\Psi(x,t)$, $ \left| \Psi (x,t)\right>$, and $\left |s(t)\right>$. I'm confident in what is meant by $\Psi$ (it's the function taking $(x,t) \mapsto \left<x|s(t)\right>$). $x$ and $\left |x\right>$ are confusing to me as well

Comment: But anyways this is just me being confused on a lot of things . I'll have to study this in more detail

Comment: @DWade64 it’s mainly just a statement that $\left|\Psi(x,t)\right>$ and $\left|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>$ are the same thing just with respect to a different basis. Think of $\left|\Psi(x,t)\right>$ as $\left|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>$ just with respect to the position eigenbasis so similarly $\Phi(p,t)$ is also just with respect to the momentum eigenbasis or: $$\left|\Phi(p,t)\right>=\sum_{i \in I} \left|p_i\right>\left<p_i|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>$$ where again $I$ is some indexing set.

Comment: @DWade64 if you look at some other texts (griffiths briefly mentions it) we can use something called the Projection operator, and it is defined as: $$\mathbb{P}_i = \left|i\right>\left<i\right|$$ from here it is relative straight forward to see that $$\mathbb{I}=\sum_i \left|i\right>\left<i\right|=\sum_i \mathbb{P}_i$$ where im using $\mathbb{I}$ to represent the identity operator. Now combine this with our original definition of $\left|\Psi(x,t)\right>$ and see if you notice anything cool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still a vector, just with an uncountably infinite number of components (one component for each value of $x$).

Comment: But isnt the inner product of two vectors a scalar? So with Griffiths definition since: $$\Psi(x,t)=\left<x|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>$$ Then $\Psi(x,t)$ is the inner product of two vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ then wouldnt that mean that $\Psi(x,t)$ is a scalar? I figured that it must still be a vector, but I dont see how it is from the definition in Griffiths.

Comment: @AlexSampson What you're missing here is that though the _output_ of the function $\Psi$ is a scalar, that does not mean that the _function itself_ is a scalar. This is analogous to many other situations in linear algebra; for example, a 2x2 matrix is a map that inputs a 2D vector and outputs a 2D vector, but is not itself a 2D vector.

Comment: @AlexSampson For another example, the components of the velocity vector are real numbers. That does not mean that the velocity vector itself is a real number. The inner products you're looking at are the components of a vector.

Comment: oh so in his definition is the $\Psi(x,t)$ is the $i^{th}$ component of the vector $$\left|\Psi(x,t)\right>=\sum_i \left|x_i\right>\left<x_i|\mathscr{s}(t)\right>$$ where $\left|x_i\right>$ are all the different eigenfunctions of the position operator. Is that the correct reasoning. (hopefully that sum means what i want it to mean i'm just getting used to Dirac notation.)

Comment: @AlexSampson Yes, that's the idea. In the interest of precision, $i$ runs over an uncountable set in your notation.